# Adding new segments to a Animated Pie Chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, pie-chart

I am unable to add a segment to a D3.js pie chart. I know I need to use `.enter()` and `.append()` to stage the new data -- but I am not sure how to apply that when I have the arcs grouped (which I need for the labels).

Here is my update function:

```
var updateChart = function(dataset) {
  arcs.data(donut(dataset));
  arcs.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);
  sliceLabel.data(donut(dataset));
  sliceLabel.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")"; })
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
      if (d.value === 0) { return 1e-6; }
      else { return 1; }
    });
};
```

How I setup the initial graph:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * .4)
  .outerRadius(radius);
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var arc_grp = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "arcGrp")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");
var label_group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lblGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

var arcs = arc_grp.selectAll("path")
  .data(donut(data));
arcs.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.8)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .each(function(d) { return this.current = d; });

var sliceLabel = label_group.selectAll("text")
  .data(donut(data));
sliceLabel.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "arcLabel")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")"; })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
    if (d.value === 0) { return 1e-6; }
    else { return 1; }
  })
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.label; });
```

Complete jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kPM5L/

What is a clean way to add the new data to the chart?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by grouped arcs. For adding the new data, do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kPM5L/1/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff exactly. If you reply with that I would be happy to accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the transition to work smoothly, you need to add the code that you're using initially to your update function as well. Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kPM5L/1/).

And some code to make SO happy -- this is what needs to be in the update function as well:

```
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("stroke", "white")
.attr("stroke-width", 0.8)
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
.attr("d", arc)
.each(function(d) { return this.current = d; });

.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class", "arcLabel")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")"; })
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
  if (d.value === 0) { return 1e-6; }
  else { return 1; }
})
.text(function(d) { return d.data.label; });
```