# d3.js changing data on click (multiple instances of Donut Chart )

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to make a data visualisation with d3.js. Im new to d3 and i think i did not quite understand completely how to change data with a click, so i need your help!

Thats what i've got so far(which i'm quite happy that it works):

```
 /*-------------------------data is parsed and proceedet above----------------------------------------------------*/

        var SVGWidth = 1670;
        var SVGeight = 800;
        var kreis = 1;
        var ringArea = 1;
        var width = 1;
        var multi = 3.5;


        var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['#FFFFFF', '#DADAD9', '#9D9C9C']);
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(function(d) {
            donutWidth = Math.sqrt(d.data.WHI1 / Math.PI + Math.pow(d.data.E1, 2)) * multi - d.data.E1 * multi
            return donutWidth;
        }).outerRadius(function(d, i) {
            width = Math.sqrt(d.data.WHI1 / Math.PI + Math.pow(d.data.E1, 2)) * multi
            return width;
        });
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
            return d.country;
        }).sort(null);

        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', SVGWidth)
        .attr('height', SVGeight)
        .append("g")

        svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data1995).
        enter().append("g")
        .attr({
            transform: function(d, i) {
                var pos = coord2Pt(geo[i][1], geo[i][2], 1.0);
                return "translate(" + pos.x + ", " + pos.y + ")";
            }
        }).selectAll('path').data(function(country, i) {
            return pie(country.map(function(value) {
                return {
                    country: value,
                    WHI1: WHI1[i],
                    E1: E1[i]
                };
            }));
        })
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', function(d) {
            return arc(d);
        }).attr('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(i);
        });
    });
})(window.d3);
```

This results in this Visualisation:
[Worldmap donut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajHbt.png)

What i'm now trying to do is to change my Data from "data1995" to "data2015", both "WHI1" to "WHI2" and both "E1" to "E2" with a click on the "test" button. In addition it would be great if they would change with a transition.

I'm not shure if I'm on the right path to accomplish this but is tried this so far:

```
            d3.select("button").on('click', function() {
            console.log("click")
            d3.selectAll('path').transition().duration(500).attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            }).attr("d", arc).each(function(d) {
                this._current = d;
            });

            function change(data2015) {
                return pie(country.map(function(value) {
                    return {
                        country: value,
                        WHI2: WHI2[i],
                        E2: E2[i]
                    };
                }));
                path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
            }

            function arcTween(a) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
                this._current = i(0);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(i(t));
                };
           }
        });
```

Thats what I've found on another thread on here ([update d3 pie chart with new data.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717519/update-d3-pie-chart-with-new-data-json))
but in fact i'm not even shure if i translated it right to my script and i'm curious if that would work with all of my instances of the Donut.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a button with a onclick property, for example an update() function.

This function loads data2015 and change WHI1 to WHI2 and E1 to E2.
So this function is quite similar to what you have already written.

I think this approach is better because you do not need to update the chart as frequently as in the link you posted

I've found an example links, look at these:

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much! 
After 12 hours of trys and errors yesterday, i've tried them all. 
For now i dont know whats the matter why it doesnt work and how to apply  those examples to my code Correctly.