# D3 Uncaught TypeError: path.data is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am quitte a newbie to D3.js and for a project i need to make a donutchart with data that changes every 2 seconds. But every time I try to change the data i get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: path.data is not a function

I used [this code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) as an example for the change function

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>D3 donuttest</title>
 <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.jss"></script> 
 <style>

  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
 <div id="chartwrapper">
  
 </div>
</body>
<script>
 var wrapper="#chartwrapper";
 var dummydata=70;
 var data=[dummydata,100-dummydata];
 var width = 460,
     height = 300,
     radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

 var color = d3.scale.category20();

 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
     .sort(null);

 var arc = d3.svg.arc()
     .innerRadius(radius - 100)
     .outerRadius(radius - 50);

 var svg = d3.select(wrapper).append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

 var path = svg.selectAll("path")
     .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("path")
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
     .attr("d", arc)
     .transition()
     .ease("bounce")
     .duration(1000)
     .attrTween("d", initTween);
     var label=svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "display")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-30,10)");
var labeltext=label.append("text")
    .attr("font-size","2rem")
    .text(dummydata + "%");
    function change(data){
     labeltext.text(data[0] + "%");
     path.data(pie(data));
     path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d",arcTween);
    };
    //animation tween for when graph is drawn
 function initTween(b) {
    b.innerRadius = 0;
    var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
    return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
 }
 //animation for when data is changed
 function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function(t) {
     return arc(i(t));
    };
 };
 //simulating data changes
 setInterval(function() {
    dummydata = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    data=[dummydata,100-dummydata];
    console.log(data)
  change(data);
 },2000);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight modification of your code that might help you. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719167/1612562) as a guide.

The modifications include:

- only store the result of `append()` in the `path` variable;
- when first drawing the chart, store the initial angles in `_current` instead of using the `initTween` function.

```js
var wrapper = "#chartwrapper";
var dummydata = 70;
var data = [dummydata, 100 - dummydata];

var width = 460,
  height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 100)
  .innerRadius(radius - 50);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null);

var svg = d3.select(wrapper).append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
  .append("path");

path.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .transition()
  .ease("bounce")
  .duration(1000)
  .each(function(d) {
    this._current = d;
  }); // store the initial angles

var label = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "display")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-30,10)");

var labeltext = label.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", "2rem")
  .text(dummydata + "%");

function change(data) {
  labeltext.text(data[0] + "%");
  path.data(pie(data));
  path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs

}

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

setInterval(function() {
  dummydata = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
  data = [dummydata, 100 - dummydata];
  console.log(data)
  change(data);
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartwrapper"></div>
```